# Why are there so many free movable DMA32 blocks on the x86 64bits platform?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

Why are there so many free movable DMA32 blocks on the x86 64bits platform?

As its name, I think it is used for DMA. But 730 free blocks(with order 10) means more than 1GB memory. How huge the memory is!

`cat /proc/pagetypeinfo` says:

```
sudo cat /proc/pagetypeinfo
Page block order: 9
Pages per block:  512

    Free pages count per migrate type at order       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10
    Node    0, zone      DMA, type    Unmovable      0      1      1      0      2      1      1      0      1      0      0
    Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Movable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      3
    Node    0, zone      DMA, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone      DMA, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone    DMA32, type    Unmovable      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      0
    Node    0, zone    DMA32, type      Movable      3      4      5      4      2      3      4      4      1      2    730
    Node    0, zone    DMA32, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone    DMA32, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone    DMA32, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone   Normal, type    Unmovable     17      2      2      1      0      0      0      1      2     13      0
    Node    0, zone   Normal, type      Movable     15      4      0     15      4      1      1      0      0      0    934
    Node    0, zone   Normal, type  Reclaimable      0      6     21      9      6      3      3      1      2      0      0
    Node    0, zone   Normal, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    Node    0, zone   Normal, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
    
    Number of blocks type     Unmovable      Movable  Reclaimable   HighAtomic      Isolate
    Node 0, zone      DMA            1            7            0            0            0
    Node 0, zone    DMA32            2         1526            0            0            0
    Node 0, zone   Normal          160         2314           78            0            0
```

Comment: Probably you mixed two things: 1) DMA **capable** memory regions, 2) physically present amount of memory. You see, the address space is much bigger than the real physical memory in most of the computers (only high performance servers have TiBs of memory).

Comment: Glad to see you again. DMA32 ZONE is **one** of the DMA **capable** memory regions. Am I right? There are 730 free blocks with order 10(i.e. 2MB ) means more than **1GB** memory.  Where goes wrong？